# Can this CORS error be avoided on Windows 7?(I tried both Chrome and Firefox)

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox, security-policy, cors

```
Access to fetch at 'https://ip-51-105-104-76.dditscdn.com/api/8/envelope/? 
sentry_key=...&sentry_version=7&sentry_client=sentry.javascript.browser%2F7.51.2' 
from origin 'https://www.livejasmin.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' 
to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Today I started receiving this error on Windows 7, on 2 different browsers, Firefox and Chrome. However the site is working fine on Windows 10.

Can this error be avoived somehow?

Comment: That this has worked on Windows 10 tells you that Windows 7 is several years too old to update properly.

Comment: I'm not ready yet. Is there a workaround for it until I'm ready to update?

Comment: No updates for Windows 7 and many other apps on Windows 7

Comment: This problem is different, I think there must be a workaround for it.

Comment: Please read and understand: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72211930 You need an up-to-date  browser for starters. Something that you can't have in Windows 7. Suggestion: Use Linux. There are many good distros that'll work in your old computer (if that's the reason for not upgrading Windows).

Comment: And what is “the site”?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the resource you are trying to access, at `https://ip-51-105-104-76.dditscdn.com/api/8/envelope/1`, uses [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://aws.amazon.com/what-is/cross-origin-resource-sharing/). To prevent cross-site request *forgery*, the site requires the browser and operating system (OS) to be trusted.

Apparently, Windows 7 does not provide that level of trust. You *might* try an extension, such as [User Agent Switcher and Manager](https://add0n.com/useragent-switcher.html) for *Firefox*, to "spoof" the OS... at the risk that it *might get your account disabled*.

The better approach would be to move to a new, supported OS. Microsoft has deprecated Windows 7, and no longer provides security updates.

If your system cannot support a modern version of Windows (note that support for Windows 10 ends in less than a year!), then test running another OS from a bootable USB. It would take less than an hour to make and to boot from a [64-bit Live Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started) USB, which comes with Firefox already installed. If the system is 32-bit, there are [other alternatives](https://www.makeuseof.com/linux-distros-with-32-bit-support/).